# PrimeNG Multi-select show strange fomat

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

PrimeNG p-multiselect show strange.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHzh7.png)

I have created a new project, and put all dependencies from the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cfjspw?file=src%2Findex.html

practically all code from example above, except the includes stylesheet css on index.html because it was showing error of Mime... (And I tried to solved it...)

Comment: Try to keep these imports in your global style sheet `@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';@import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css');
@import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css');`

Comment: Thanks for advise.
I put @import '/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';....
but I received a error: ERROR in ./src/assets/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\primeicons\primeicons.css'
... 
And I checked and the path is correct.

Comment: Or try this, remove those changes and keep these in your `angular.json` styles array `"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
],`, oh and you must [install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng) first `npm install primeng primeicons --save`

Comment: Also these work for me in `styles.scss` file`@import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "~primeng/primeicons/primeicons.css";`

Comment: Resolved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### First Install using command **`npm install primeng primeicons --save`**

> **Option 1:~**
>
> **Add these to styles array in angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
]
```

> **Option 2:~**
>
> **Add these `styles.scss` file**

```
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"; 
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"; 
@import "~primeng/primeicons/primeicons.css";
```

Comment: Kindly accept the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved inserting

```html
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
]
```

Thanks